Polars not using all available CPU
I'm running code that performs vectorized calculations using the lazy Polars approach. The code loops approximately 4,000 times and takes about 4 seconds to execute. However, when I check my CPU usage, I see that only 25% of the CPU is being utilized. I would like to increase CPU usage to 80%–100%.
I'm running this on my Windows computer. Below is an example of a condition class where the evaluate function is executed each time in the loop. How can I modify the code or configuration to ensure that more CPU resources are used?
from src.conditions.base_condition import BaseCondition
import polars as pl
from src.utils.types import TimeFrameDataFrames
from src.enums.types_enums import TimeFrame

short_avg_period_options = [20, 30, 40, 50]
long_avg_period_options = [100, 140, 160, 200]

class MovingAverageCondition(BaseCondition):
    def __init__(self, short_avg_period: int = 20, long_avg_period: int = 200, bullish: bool = True, timeframe: TimeFrame = TimeFrame.M5):
        self.short_avg_period = short_avg_period
        self.long_avg_period = long_avg_period
        self.bullish = bullish
        self.timeframe = timeframe

    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        return 'MovingAverageCondition'

    def get_parameters(self) -> dict:
        return {
            'short_avg_period': self.short_avg_period,
            'long_avg_period': self.long_avg_period,
            'bullish': self.bullish,
            'timeframe': self.timeframe
        }

    def required_timeframes(self) -> list:
        return [self.timeframe]

    def evaluate(self, dfs: TimeFrameDataFrames, **kwargs) -> pl.Series:
        """
        Evaluates the condition using Polars DataFrame from the specified timeframe.
        Returns a Polars Series indicating where the condition is met.
        """
        timeframe_df = dfs.get(self.timeframe)

        if timeframe_df is None:
            raise ValueError(f"{self.timeframe.value} data is required for MovingAverageCondition.")

        # Use lazy evaluation for performance optimization
        timeframe_df_lazy = timeframe_df.lazy()

        # Calculate short and long moving averages (lazy)
        sma_short = pl.col('Close').rolling_mean(window_size=self.short_avg_period)
        sma_long = pl.col('Close').rolling_mean(window_size=self.long_avg_period)

        # Bullish or bearish condition check (lazy)
        if self.bullish:
            condition = (pl.col('Close') > sma_short) & (sma_short > sma_long)
        else:
            condition = (pl.col('Close') < sma_short) & (sma_short < sma_long)

        # Collect the result and fill any null values
        result_df = timeframe_df_lazy.select(condition.alias("condition")).collect()

        return result_df["condition"].fill_null(False)

    @staticmethod
    def get_instances():
        instances = []
        for short in short_avg_period_options:
            for long in long_avg_period_options:
                instances.append(MovingAverageCondition(short_avg_period=short, long_avg_period=long))
        
        return instances


import os
import psutil
import polars as pl
import time

class TrackPerformance:
    @staticmethod
    def track_cpu_usage(func):
        # Measure CPU usage during Polars execution
        cpu_usage_before = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=None)
        start_time = time.time()
        
        # Execute your Polars operation here (example)
        func()
        
        end_time = time.time()
        cpu_usage_after = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=None)
        
        print(f"CPU usage before: {cpu_usage_before}%")
        print(f"CPU usage after: {cpu_usage_after}%")
        print(f"Execution time: {end_time - start_time:.4f} seconds")


Vectorized doesn't mean parallelized or multithreaded. Neither does lazy evaluation. Lazy evaluation means that instead of loading everything in memory before processing it, you process stuff as you load it. If every processing step is performed by a different thread (easier to do with pipelines), by the time you finish loading you've also finished processing.

well I saw polar wrote they take care parallel by default... so every loop I should insert my process into array and use ThreadPoolExecutor?

No. Polars won't fix your code as if by magic. Your code loads the same data multiple times, which means the CPU is wasted the second time. Instead of using pl.col('Close').rolling_mean... twice, why not use df.with_columns (sma_short...,sma_long...) to add those columns in the frame itself? Perhaps Polars will realize you're processing the same data and optimize this. The current code prevents any optimization. In general, instead of looping or performing operations one by one, you should try to combine them in pipelines, so that Polars can decide what to execute concurrently.

Even condition is known before the data is loaded and could be part of a pipeline

What you mean add 2 columns when they required different calculations and you say instead of looping I should combine them but I still need to loop in order to make the pipeline

You're calling .collect() inside a loop - which blocks. If you return LazyFrames instead and gather them in a list, you can use pl.collect_all(list_of_frames) and Polars will compute them all in parallel on its own threadpool.

Oh k I see, and if some of the calculation cant be with lazy df I cant achieve that? Also can I combine it with python threadpool and let them compete resources? ty

It would depend on why it can be lazy? Looking at this code again: it seems you don't need the df at all here. If you build a list of condition expressions in the loop - you can call them all in a single .select() call at the end. It's much easier to help if "minimal runnable examples" are provided - the current one is a bit "abstract".
